# How to display block with animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make block appear with animation from top to normal position. I thought it's possible to do with after selector.

So, I want to click on some element and show another element with animation.

Here is the code for now.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .title{
            padding: 20px 20px;
            background-color: aqua;
            width: 50px;
            height: 200px;
        }

        .added-content{
            display: none;
            background-color: black;
            width: 50px;
            height: 200px;
        }

        .added-content--active{
            display: block;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title">
        some title
    </div>

    <div class="added-content">
        addon
    </div>

    <script>
        const title=document.querySelector('.title');
        const contenAdded=document.querySelector('.added-content');

        title.addEventListener('click',()=>{
            contenAdded.classList.toggle('added-content--active');
        })

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the link to code Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-davinci-1dqujt?file=/index.html

Is there any way to show the block with animation, so it would look beautiful? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) and [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) instead of `display`

```
.added-content {
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.added-content--active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .title {
        padding: 20px 20px;
        background-color: aqua;
        width: 50px;
        height: 200px;
      }

      .added-content {
        background-color: black;
        width: 50px;
        height: 200px;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s;
      }

      .added-content--active {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="title">
      some title
    </div>

    <div class="added-content">
      addon
    </div>

    <script>
      const title = document.querySelector(".title");
      const contenAdded = document.querySelector(".added-content");

      title.addEventListener("click", () => {
        contenAdded.classList.toggle("added-content--active");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With keyframes:

```js
const title = document.querySelector(".title");
const contenAdded = document.querySelector(".added-content");

title.addEventListener("click", () => {
  contenAdded.classList.toggle("added-content--active");
});
```

```css
.title {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.added-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;  
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

.added-content--active {
  display: block;
  animation: slideup 0.5s;
}

@keyframes slideup {
  from {
    top: -100px;
  }

  to {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="title">some title</div>
<div class="added-content">addon</div>
```